# How to calculate the correct size to zoom a WebView?

Tags: cocoa, macos, webkit

I have a WebView in my window. When the user clicks on the Zoom button (the green button on the top left of the window), I want to change the size of the window such that the WebView is just large enough to show the web page, as recommended in the Mac HCI guidelines.

Question is: how to I go about calculating the size of the WebView to zoom to?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Oh sorry, then you should reverse it :)

```
- (IBAction)resizeToView:(id)sender
{
    // webview content sub/document-view
    NSView *docView =[[[webView mainFrame] frameView] documentView]; 
    NSRect docRect = [docView frame];

    // height and width
    int height = docRect.size.height;
    int width = docRect.size.width;

    NSRect frame = [window frame];
    int delta = height - frame.size.height;

    // y/height
    frame.origin.y -= delta;
    frame.size.height += delta;

    // x/width
    frame.size.width = width; 

    [window setFrame:frame display:YES]; 
}
```

Comment: I don't think so. There are times where there is a need to readjust the width and height of the WebView, aren't there?

Comment: First of all 1) webpages without a width fit to the window, these do not have frame width/height, 2) I don't know the sizes of items in the view, these you have to ajust for your self. The code above works for my example code.